# The second fundamental form and isometry.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, self-learning

What is the effect on the second fundametal form of asurface of applying an isometry of $\Bbb R^3$ ? Or a dilation?

I posted its answer.

[image]

This answer is not understandable for me in general. Please is someone explains it, I'll be happy. Thank you.

Comment: Where is your problem, exactly? Check this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589416/why-first-fundamental-form-and-second-fundamental-form-are-the-same to see the definition of the coefficients of the second fundamental form. Can you compute the effect of a transformation $\sigma\mapsto P\sigma+a$ on the normal vector $n$ to the surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r=r(u,v)$ be a parametrization of a given surface and let $n=n(u,v)$ denote the normal vector. We use the notation

$$II:=Ldu^2 + 2Mdudv + Ndv^2$$
where $L = r_{uu}\cdot  n$; $M = r_{uv}\cdot  n$; $N = r_{vv}\cdot  n$ for the second fundamental form.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589416/why-first-fundamental-form-and-second-fundamental-form-are-the-same) I proved that the first fundamental form is invariant under 
$r\mapsto r':= Or+b$, where $O$ is a $3\times 3$ orthogonal matrix and $b$ real. Note that $r'=r'(u,v)$. and

$$r'_j=\sum_{k=1}^3 O_{jk}r_k+b_j, $$

for all $j=1,2,3$.

Then $r'_u:=\frac{\partial r'}{\partial u}=O\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}$ and $r'_v:=\frac{\partial r'}{\partial v}=O\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}$, as $O$ does not depend on $(u,v)$; similarly  $r'_{uu}=r_{uu}$ and $r'_{vv}=r_{vv}$. The normal vector w.r.t. $r'$ is then

$$n'=r'_u \times r'_v=\pm n,$$

as proved in the original reference (prop. A.1.6). It follows that

$$L'=  r'_{uu}\cdot  n'=\pm r_{uu}\cdot n=\pm L,$$
$$M' = r'_{uv}\cdot  n'= \pm r_{uv}\cdot n=\pm M,$$

and similarly for the remaining coefficient of the second fundamental form, i.e. $N$.

The case of dilations is treated analogously. Please check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589416/why-first-fundamental-form-and-second-fundamental-form-are-the-same) again for the explicit computations.

Comment: You are really wonderrful!! Thanks to you, I'll pass the exam:)

Comment: From the very nature of the questions you post, I think that it is important for you to understand the chain rule for functions in $\mathbb R^n$, the definition of a parametrized surface & normal vector (can you compute examples of normal vectors?).

Comment: yes i can. and yes i am asking in order to learn better

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of the question, to understand the effect on the second fundamental form of  applying a dilation, lets consider a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the metric induced by the usual inner product
$\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$.

Then we have a parameterisation $F$ of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the dilation
$\tilde{F} = \psi F$, where $\psi$ is a constant (independent of the spacial coordinates).
We then notice that

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \tilde{F}}{\partial x_i} = \psi\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}, \quad \mbox{and}\quad 
\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{F}}{\partial x_j\partial x_i} = \psi\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_j\partial x_i},
\end{equation}

from which follows
\begin{equation}
\tilde{g}_{ij} = 
\left\langle \frac{\partial \tilde{F}}{\partial x_i} , \frac{\partial \tilde{F}}{\partial x_j} \right\rangle =
\left\langle \psi \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} ,\psi \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_j} \right\rangle = 
\psi^2 g_{ij}.
\end{equation}

Since the unit normal vector $\nu$ of the hypersurface $F$ is also a normal unit vector for
the hypersurface $\tilde{F}$, we compute the second fundamental form as
\begin{equation}
\tilde{h}_{ij} = \left\langle \frac{\partial^2 \tilde{F}}{\partial x_j\partial x_i} , \nu\right\rangle = 
\psi \left\langle \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_j\partial x_i} , \nu\right\rangle  =
\psi h_{ij}.
\end{equation}